# Android tv lagging after sleepping (Mi box 4)

Tags: android-tv, xiaomi

**Environment:**

- Xiaomi Mi Box 4
- Android 8.1.0

My box is pretty much useless after sleep. When I try to watch something in youtube or netflix the image or sound gets stucked very frequently and makes a weird noise.
It's so slow that I can't use it unless I reboot it, but just for a few time.

Any configuration to avoid this issue or to improve the performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution that improved the performance was by doing the following steps:

1. Enable developer options by tapping 6x build in about.
2. Enable stay awake in developers options.
3. Disable hdmi cec in mi box settings to disable auto sleep.

Your mi box won't sleep and is stable.